# bucket brigade type of message sending and receiving

Tags: mqtt

MQTT is based on broker where sender sending the message and receiver gets it. But what if something wrong with the broker then the message would get lost. I am looking for bucket brigade type of message passing and sending. The message would get propagated.

Answer (score 0):

If you send messages to a MQTT broker at a QOS level of greater than 0 and the broker is down at the time then the message will be queued on the client until the broker comes back. You should not loose messages if the right QOS is used.

Comment: queued on the client? where that info got stored at?  Also can you have a broker within the same network, not outside to the internet?

Comment: If the client library supports QOS > 0 then they should implement local storage for messages they can not send. The Paho (Java and C) clients do this. You can configure the location on disk or implement your own storage. As for where the broker is, you can run your broker where ever you want, there are several to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned take a look at the mqtt options of `qos` but also `retained` messages and `last will and testament`